# What is the maximum number of people that will join a settlement?

Tags: fallout-4

I've got two settlements on the go that I'm paying attention to - Sanctuary and the Starlight Drive In. Both of these settlements have radio towers and beds and all resources in the green however they appear to have stopped growing at 10 people in each settlement even though happiness is above 80 and I've got 15+ beds at each location.

What is the maximum number of people that will join a settlement?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Temporary charisma buffs will make it possible to get a lot more settlers according to this [steam thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/496881136902383792/)

> Charisma boosting gear also increases the max, the calculation is 10+CHA stat(maximum of 11 with bobblehead)+CHA bosting gear/drugs=max pop, though there are some conflicting reports about the longevity of that solution

[This reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3slqsv/psa_your_maximum_population_in_a_settlement_is_10/) also confirms going over 22 but reverting to normal when going back :

> I had the same thing with vanilla. If you go back to the settlement it will revert to 10+CHA. The number keeps increasing if your out. Then it remembers it can only have so many and the institute comes for them (fast traveled back and syths were attacking so it is headcannon now)

The number is 10 + 1 per charisma point [as written here](http://www.tentonhammer.com/guides/fallout-4/fallout-4-settlement-building-and-management-guide-power-water-food-and-more):

> Successful settlements need four critical things: beds, food, water, and defense. In the same respect, power is required to meet these needs beyond the most basic sense, especially for defense. There is an easy and quick way to understand how much of each you need:
>
> - Beds: One per settler (max of 10 settlers plus 1 settler per Charisma point).
> - Food: One food per settler.
> - Water: One water per settler.
> - Defense: One point per settler, although more is more helpful.
> - Power: Add all of the power consumption things you need running, that’s the required power.
>
> As noted, you’ll probably have a max of 11 to 20 settlers, depending on your build.

Seems the defense's value needs to be higher for a safe settlement, as per the comment from DCShannon :

> You want enough defense to cover you food + your water. The number of settlers seems irrelevant. Keeping the defense over this value has resulted in entire playthroughs without a single attack on a settlement.

So make sure you have enough water, food and defense with at least 1 charisma to get up to 11 and more.

So the max should be 21 as it is possible [to get a SPECIAL over 10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242637/can-special-stats-be-increased-past-10), with charisma at 11, that would make possible to have 21 settlers with the same amount of beds, food, water and defense.

Comment: Can you use "You're SPECIAL" to get a CHA to 12 or is the cap 11? That's not worth it's own question.

Comment: The book will not let you increase past 10.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I think that source is wrong, my max settlers per settlement seems to be pegged at 10 + charisma + local trader rank (2)

Comment: Actually, if you get to 10, then get addicted to Daddy-O (I think) and get a Charisma penalty you can use the book to get to 11, then find the bobble head to get to 12!

Comment: You want enough defense to cover you food + your water. The number of settlers seems irrelevant. Keeping the defense over this value has resulted in entire playthroughs without a single attack on a settlement.

Comment: @dcshannon I've had settlements with over 4:1 ratio of defense to supply that get attacked.  Though it's possible it's simply glitched as sometimes the values indirectly displays as 0 in the workshop menu in the pipboy

Comment: @z' What difficulty was that on? I've played up through Very Hard now, but haven't tried Survival yet. Attacks on settlements seem almost mythical to me at this point.

Comment: @DCShannon survival difficulty

Comment: My max number is 23 that I reached so far. But capacity at the top left in building mode is at 1/5.

Comment: TL;DR. **10 plus your charisma.**