# How can I have 22 settlers?

Tags: fallout-4

So, can someone explain how I have 22 settlers in Sanctuary when limit is 20? I have 10 charisma level and 2 local leaders. These are my stats:

Food: 42

Water: 67

Power: 70

Defense: 106

Beds: 21 (I didn't expect to get 22 people lol)

Comment: Btw, the max should be [21 settlers](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/242767/61395)

Comment: Oh thx. Still strange how there can be 22..

Comment: Temporary buffs to charisma also permits the limit to exceed 22, see my updated answer. There's people reporting 29+ settlers when they are away.

Answer (score 5):

10 base + 11 more from your CHA level of 10 = 21.

Adding Codsworth to this makes 22.

Answer (score 3):

I have the Charisma bobblehead and max Charisma, and can maintain 24 settlers per settlement. I'm not wearing special clothing, and it happened because I had 5 people at the settlement, and then sent 10 from one other settlement, and 9 from another, on accident because I thought I had sent the same ones a couple of times.

The 24 people are there to stay and they're operating 17 shops + plenty of food and water + 100+ defense, stuck at 97% happiness, but all I've seen online says 21 and 22, nah, I definitely have 24.

I could assign them all and I have left since on another save because the 100% happiness is taking forever, just to come back multiple times and they're all still there.

- Xbox One

Answer (score 1):

Caravans passing through will temporarily increase the number of settlers you have in the settlement. I believe the same applies for faction patrols as well.

Comment: But this has only happend in Sanctuary so far and I have a lot of supply lines across my other settlement. The castle has 20 settlers and have caravans passing though there

Comment: Do we know if companions stationed at a settlement add to the number?

Comment: Actually no idea! Although I don't have any companions in Sanctuary only settlers

Comment: @Ilendius including Codsworth?

Comment: No sorry he is at Sanctuary. Forgot that the little guy actually was a companion.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the settler limit is actually 10+charisma+local leader rank.

Most of my settlements are pegged at that number instead of just 10+charisma.

Comment: Are you still seeing this behavior, because I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @Dallium i've started a new game so I haven't had time to get that many settlers yet.  My previous game seemed very glitchy, sanctuary would fluxuate between 22-24 inhabitants even though the max should've been 18.

Answer (score 0):

Have 10 charisma.

Use a drug that reduces charisma then use "you're special" book near Shaun's bed and select charisma. The pick up the charisma bobblehead.

Congratulations, now you have 12 permanent charisma!

Comment: "You're SPECIAL" doesn't reproducibly increase stats past 10 (unless there was a stealth patch I missed). To the best of my knowledge, we don't know if that's a bug or WAI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it seems special settlers does not count in the limit (like the 'Long' familly), I've got 19 settlers in Santuary but only 6 in charisma

Answer (score 0):

I have 29 settlers at The Castle. My charisma is at 15 when I have my special clothing on that boosts my charisma. You have to send settlers from your other settlements to reach 29. I haven't figured out a way to get past 29, if it's even possible. I'm on PS4 btw.