# What influences the availability in the settlements supply line target selection?

Tags: fallout-4

I've seen nice "loops" of supply lines on the net.

But in my game, I often cannot select nearby settlements as targets in the "supply line target selection list" when setting up a supply line, because they are greyed out.
The further I progress in the game the more confusing does the supply line target selection become. It seems to get smaller and smaller.

e.g. in *Nordhagen Beach* I cannot select *Finch Farm* nor *County Crossing*.
Why is that? Can I influence this by changing other supply lines?

**EDIT1**: Seems like I have to clarify my personal game state here:
I have the local leader perk. I have many settlements, which I usually build by building a recruitment bacon and assigning the first settler which walks into the newly aquired settlement to be provisioner. This worked fine for the first 10 settlements. The issue came up only recently, namely on the settlements of *Nordhagen Beach* and *Somerville Place*.

I do not intend to build a supply line hub, I just want to connect the settlements to the nearest settlement in the already existing network (which is not a closed circle, no has it a central hub)

**EDIT2**: Here is a screenshot of my current supply lines and the target selection list, viewed in Finch Farm. It's not showing Finch Farm being disabled, because I have no savegame from before setting up the supply line and later savegames (after I already created a line to a different settlement) seem to have fixed themself.

[image: the current supply line network]
[image: the target selection list, viewed in Northagen Beach]

Comment: From my experience, you cannot select a settlement which already has a direct supply line with the one you're currently in. Are you sure you didn't already send a settler from Finch Farm or County Crossing to Nordhagen Beach?

Comment: it happened multiple times and the settlements where always newly aquired, I tried to send the first settler which was attracted by the recruitment beacon. I frist thought that settlements can only have "two connectors", but this is not the case.

Comment: I second Nolonar's comment. However with my charisma set at 90, and my settlements averaging +40 people, assigning anything can take a while. If I'm not careful I can over assign the same route during this time. Check your supply lines in the map (press `c`). Assign someone and then wait or fast travel (or both). Then check the map again. ~ It didn't seem to be working and I assigned way too many people to the same route; now there's traffic on the highways. Advice: do not use a settlement in the corner (Sanctuary) to send out everywhere. Personally I use Jamaica for this.

Comment: I am 100% sure that I did not already setup supply lines. It's happening in brand new settlements and there are like 4-5 of the other settlements disabled in the target list. The supply map screen does not show any supply lines to this new settlement. Maybe I can try to setup the supply line from the existing settlements to the new one instead of linking from the new settlement to the older ones, might be worth a try.

Comment: What are you playing on? Any mods? Do you have the Local Leader perk? Do both places have radio beacons? When you say disabled, you mean absent or grayed out?

Comment: @Mazura I'm only talking about the "target selection list" when setting up a supply line. Some settlements in this list are disabled, which means grayed out. That usually means you already have a line to that settlement - just that I do not. Yes, of course I have local leader. As mentioned above, I built a reqruitment bacon and try to assign the first new settler which walks into the settlement

Comment: I have the same issue the OP has.  I use the same build order mentioned in the edit.  I wonder if this is some kind of bug where the supply lines are not fully linking correctly as soon as a new settlement is obtained or something.  One thing to try might be saving the game just after obtaining the new settlement, then exiting and relaunching the game, maybe waiting 24 hrs, then try to assign the supply line.  I might try this tonight.

Comment: I did some tests: The disabled items are not the same everywhere. I can create a supply line from Finch Farm to Northagen Beach, but not vice versa. Most places cannot link to Hangman's Alley, but Hangman's Alley can link to all but Abernathy's Farm and Starlight Drive In. I traveled between the settlements (without doing anything) and now I can link from Northagen Beach to Finch Farm! IMHO the supply line target selection is arbitrarily buggy and there is no correct answer to this question.

Comment: @dube Your observation of moving around combined with your self answer below is telling. If the settlement has an artificially high population (perhaps by being there with C-boosting drugs in your system or C-boosting gear on your body) from a previous visit, when you visit again, the population is corrected - people actually leave. With the newly corrected population, it may allow the supply line. I wonder, perhaps, if the person counts against the population of both settlements...

Comment: @T.J.L. I just checked, settlements with 19 (which is the amount allowed with 9 Charisma) are not available as targets too. I don't think that they count against the limit, but it's checked in the selection screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found a reason.

All those settlements which are disabled in the target list have something in common: They all report that they have reached or exceeded my current maximum of settlers, which is 19.

Two of the disabled settlements even report ridiculous 31 and 37 settlers. 
I did some tests with my settlements. Below are my findings.

**The problem can be solved by reducing the amount of settlers 1 below your current max amount of settlers per settlement.** That means, *10 plus [current charisma with all boosts] minus 1* (see [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242767/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-people-that-will-join-a-settlement) for calculation the maximum amount of settlers per settlement)

So the solution is pretty simple: Send away settlers to under-populated settlements (e.g. your new one!)

Reaching or exceeding the maximum *does* disable this settlement in the "supply line targeting list". However, the provisioner do not count against the target settlement's counter, even when the above rule seem to suggest just that.

That might not make any sense, but it seems to fix the problem.

Comment: I've rewritten this answer afters some heavy testing

Comment: Note that this issue is resolved with beta patch 1.3, which is now available on steam

Comment: Can you define "resolved"?

Comment: the population counter does not influence the selectable settlements anymore. fixed, gone, not happening anymore - take a pick :)