# What effects do SPECIAL points have on their own?

Tags: fallout-4

Of course strength affects your carry weight, and endurance increases your max hp. What are other direct effects that come from SPECIAL points?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Strength - Determines carry weight and raises melee damage. Each point of Strength increases your carry capacity by 10 and give you a 10% bonus to unarmed/melee attacks

Perception - Directly affects lock picking and pick pocketing success, and VATS accuracy

Endurance - Determines Hit points and the rate AP decrease when sprinting. It's used to determine both your Base HP (80 + Endurance * 5) and HP per level ( 2.5 + 1/2 Endurance), and is calculated retroactively.

Charisma - Affects success rate of persuasion attempts and buy/sell prices, and the maximum number of settlers in settlements.

Intelligence - Determines how much experience you get. Every point gives you a 3% bonus.

Agility - Determines your max AP and affects ability to sneak. Each point gives you 10 AP.

Luck - Affects the recharge rate of the critical meter

[Source](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_SPECIAL)

Comment: Are there any concrete numbers?

Comment: Another direct effect is that it bars certain perks if it's too low (or it allows your to pick them if it's high enough, depending on your view). This is probably the most important aspect of the stats.

Comment: Knock it off all of you before this escalates.

Comment: Luck has a small part in *everything*, right? Including loot spawning? It's not just limited to the crit bar.

Comment: Worth noting that Charisma is the only stat that will permanently lock you out of opportunities if you start with it too low, and can't be worked around.

Comment: Each point of Intelligence also makes hacking easier by reducing the number of choices on the hacking screen.