# If I find a Bobblehead early will I be unable to raise my SPECIAL to 11?

Tags: fallout-4

I know if you have a **Strength** of 10 and find the **Strength** Bobblehead you can get to 11, but what if I find the Bobblehead earlier. Say I find it when my **Strength** is 9. Do I have  **Strength** 10 or  **Strength** 9+1? Basically, should I wait to go searching for Bobbleheads until I've maxed out a stat, or will I be able to get them all to 11 eventually regardless of when I find the Bobbleheads?

Comment: I think this is answered [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/242692/108003): "if you really want to have a stat of 11 you must wait till you raise it to 10 naturally before picking the Bobble-Head up"

Comment: If you're playing on PC, you can always use console commands to give yourself 11 SPECIAL if you collected a Bobblehead early.